# LaTeX braces flush left

Tags: equations, align, braces

I'm posting here because I couldn't find a solution to my problem on the internet. Actually, I'm working on a project and I want to make a beautiful report. But When I use the `\begin{equation}` module, the block is centered and every pair of braces are unaligned:

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaa\\
    MF_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    MF_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    MF_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I have tried eqnarray module but the equation are closer, smaller and it is not as good as equation module. Maybe it would be much better if braces are left flushed? Can someone help me?

Thank you very much :).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196 for alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  There is a `fleqn` option for several documentclasses that places displayed equations flush left + a margin specified by `\mathindent`.  Otherwise have a look at the math alignment blocks from the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One elegant solution could be a combination of the `align` and `cases` environment of the [amsmath](/questions/tagged/amsmath)-class. For optionally text inbetween you can use `intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} 
&   \begin{cases}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaa\\
    \mathit{MF}_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    \end{cases} \\ 
&   \begin{cases}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    \mathit{MF}_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    \end{cases}
    \\ 
\intertext{Some text}
&   \begin{cases}
    T_{Y} &= aaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\
    \mathit{MF}_{z}&= bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Using `\mathit{..}` (thanks to @egreg) you can add some negative space between `M` and `F` as I interpeted it as a double-digit variable, so it should be typeset like one.

Comment: If you want `MF` to be a two-letter variable, it should be `\mathit{MF}` rather than the kludgy `M\!F`.

Comment: @egreg thanks for that advice! I didn't know `\mathit` would have such an effect.